# what is the binary ( 0s and 1s) of red, green and blue color?

Tags: java, computer-science

Please tell, what is the binary code ( in 0s and 1s ) for Red, Green and Blue colors ?
For example, A is written as 65 in ASCII and 01000001 in binary language. Similarly, I want to convert Red, Green and Blue colors in binary language. How should I do that ?
I don't want any Java Class. I need only binary ( 0s and 1s ) of these colors. ( But if including Java class is necessary in answer, you can do that. )

Comment: I think you need to be more specific in how the value will be used.

Comment: I want to use Shift Operator (in Java) on them to convert them into new colors.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear about what `Red`, `Green` and `Blue` _are_. For example, in a packed int representing ARGB, red would be `0x00FF0000` (or any range from `00-FF` within that), blue would be `0x0000FF00`, and green `0x000000FF`.

Comment: Red = `1010111100` (wavelength, in nanometers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how things work.

65 and 01000001 **are the same number**.

The letter 'A' is 65 **in ASCII**. The letter 'A' is 01000001b **in ASCII**.

It is incorrect to say 'A' is 0100 0001. You can't just lop off the 'in ASCII' part. It's not 0100 0001 in the japanese codepage for example.

Colours are exactly the same. 'RED' has no universal binary form. You could ask: "In RGB888, what's red"?

A few common representations:

- In RGB888, it's 11111111 00000000 00000000. In fact, in any RGB anything, it's all 1-bits for the R part and all 0-bits for the G and B parts. That is, if you want the deepest, most basic red. What does 'red' even mean. Vermillion? A light pink?
- In YUV and other colour spaces, it's completely different. In general, this question is best answered by first determining what the colour is in the common way to write a colour down in numeric form, and if you must then have it in binary, do that.

So, to answer your question more generally:

- Red in RGB is `#FF0000`.
- `#FF0000` in binary is 11111111 00000000 00000000.

Both question ('what is red in numbers in *encoding form  you need*' and 'this number to binary') are **vastly** simpler and a ton of results can be found searching the web.

Which is simply #FF0000 (11111111 00000000 00000000). But there's also RGB656